# Split text from the database in two columns

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap based website with 2 columns(col-lg-6 and col-lg-6).
I have the ability to add text from an admin panel (articles).

How can I make it so it splits in the second div (col-lg-6) after a specific number of characters or after I insert a character or something that will represent the breakage?

I prefer a PHP solution, but Javascript/Jquery would do too

edit ***

```
 if(isset($_GET['chapter']) && !empty($_GET['chapter'])){
            $chapterid = (int)$_GET['chapter'];


                            $chaptertitle = mysql_query("SELECT bookname FROM books WHERE id=$chapterid");
                            $chaptertitle = mysql_fetch_array($chaptertitle);
                            $chaptertitle = $chaptertitle[0];


                            $chapter = mysql_query("SELECT bookContent FROM books WHERE id=$chapterid");
                            $chapter = mysql_fetch_array($chapter);
                            $chapter = $chapter[0];


                            $bookcontent = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE bookid=$id");
                            $bookcontainer = '';
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($bookcontent)){
                                $bookcontainer .= '<h2>'.$row['bookname'].'</h2>' . $row['bookContent'];
                            }
```

and this is the place where the code is printed

```
     <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6" id="paragraphs">
                        <div style="width:100%;">

                        <?php

                        //if($errors == false){
                            echo $chapter;
                        //}
                        //else{
                            //echo 'erorr madarfaker';
                        //}

                    ?>
                       </div>
                    </div>





                    <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
</div>
```

If anyone is interested in this: I made 2 fields in the admin panel and the variable that was being sent to the database was "field 1 + ' | ' + field 2" and then I used explode to display the content on 2 sides, separator being " | "

Comment: Without any code or the admin panels name it's probably impossible to help you. We'd need to know how your input data is processed (eg. does it get printed back as raw html? If so a simple <br/> in your text would do the trick). This way it's just not enough information for us to provide an efficient solution.

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Answer (score 0):

Choose an arbitrary character for your split, like "|".  Based on your posted code, use this as your echo statement:

```
 echo str_replace($chapter, "|", "</div></div><div class='col-lg-6' id='paragraphs'><div style='width:100%;'>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this solves your problem, but you can try :

```
<?php
    // An array with your database data :
    $arr = array('val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4');

    $col1 = "";
    $col2 = "";
    $flag=false;
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($arr); $i++){   
        //Break condition :
        $flag = ($arr[$i] == "val3" || $flag != true ) ? true : false;

        if(!$flag){
            $col1 .= $arr[$i];
        }
        else{
            $col2 .= $arr[$i];
        }
    }

    $html = "";
    if($col1 != ""){
        $html .= "<div class='col-lg-6'>".$col1."</div>";
    }
    if($col2 != ""){
        $html .= "<div class='col-lg-6'>".$col2."</div>";
    }

    // The two div with your content (if the break rule is found) :
    echo $html;

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in this: I made 2 fields in the admin panel and the variable that was being sent to the database was "field 1 + ' | ' + field 2" and then I used explode to display the content on 2 sides, separator being " | "

Comment: If it ended up being two separate fields, then why bother combining and splitting again?

Comment: to only keep one column in the db